# Can そうにする be placed after all adjectives to form the meaning: (to pretend to be sth)

Tags: grammar, translation

For example:
I saw 偉そうにする (to act important) in my textbook.
Could every adjective or 連用形 fit in this structure?
ex.
きれいそうにする (to act pretty)
ばかそうにする (to act like a fool)
見られなそうにする (to act as one can not see)
Does it have a negative connotation and thus a better direct translation?

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25136/45489